# VS code, jump to after closing quote/braces/parenthesis

Tags: visual-studio-code

With Visual studio Code if I'm in the middle some quote/braces/brackets/parenthesis is there a way to jump to after end of the current block?

Eg.
If

[image]

it allows me jump to the end of the quote

[image]

Or from:

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 12):

**April 2020 Update**

Yes, use `Ctrl+Shift+\`, (or `⇧ + ⌘ + \` on Mac) to jump to closest bracket. If cursor is currently in-between the brackets, first it will jump to closing bracket, each consequent press will jump between opening and closing brackets.

You can reassign the binding to your liking in Keyboard Shortcuts using `editor.action.jumpToBracket` command.

Comment: Sorry I use mac, and tried  cmd+shif+\ but doesn't work :S

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what those symbols are, but you can check them [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings), name: Jump to matching bracket. Page should show corresponding bindings depending on current OS.

Comment: This is the feature request tracking making it work even when the cursor is not on the brackets https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1772

Comment: @DanielImms it looks like feature request was implemented. give it a go.

Answer (score 10):

Use `ctrl+right` it triggers the `cursorWordEndRight` command. 
It moves the cursor by whole words. These "words" include spaces, parenthesis, commas and the likes.
You can modify the keybinding shortcut to what you desire. 
I personally use `ctrl+alt+space` for now. 
It's not perfect but it's the best alternative I have currently.

Answer (score 8):

The TabOut extension doesn't do exactly what you're describing (I think), but comes very close.

Note: I'm still trying it out so I'm not sure if I like Tab meaning different things depending on the context, but so far it's getting me pretty close to what I want.

Answer (score 2):

use Ctrl + Enter in Windows 10 if you want get outside and go downline. or Ctrl + Shift + Enter if you want get outside and go upline.

Answer (score -2):

Finally find out on Mac to jump to closing bracket/parenthese :

⌘ + ⇧ + £