# How can I make VS Code skip over a semicolon added from a snippet when "retyping" that semicolon?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I recently started programming in Java and set up *vscode* for the purpose. I have already installed the extension packs required for Java.

**The Problem**- whenever I type any command, say for example `sysout` and hit enter, vscode correctly generates `System.out.println(|);` with my cursor at the point where I have made the `|` symbol. Here, when I enter closing paranthesis, it is not actually entered and my cursor just moves forward. **Now**, when I enter `;`, I get two semicolons (semicolon is not ignored) ex.- `System.out.println();;`.

Is there a way to fix this because it's really annoying me, particularly since when I am typing really fast, I have to stop and access my trackpad to move the cursor or either press the right arrow key which disrupts the whole flow.

I tried looking online but couldn't really find any resource that solves this problem.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could just jump to the end of the line by pressing "END" on your keyboard. This way you can save yourself typing ")".

Comment: @funky I am using a Mac so, I'll have to press Cmd+right arrow which again would disrupt the flow. Is there no fix to this?

Comment: I do not know about the "double semicolon"-thing but if the "jump to the end"-thingy might help you, you can always overwrite the default keybindings to find a button (or button combination) of your liking. File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: @funky yeah, that will work but I don't want to get into that bad habit since what if I type my code on a simple text editor.

Comment: You can create your own snippet that will move the cursor to _after_ the semicolon when pressing tab (at least, that's how it works on Windows). That makes it consistent with the behavior when filling in method arguments.

Comment: @Slaw Oh ok, I could try that

Comment: Making the body of the snippet `System.out.println($1);$2` worked for me.

Comment: @Slaw you mean this is what you added on your .code_snippets file right?
Because this isn't working for me

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to make snippets. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I brought up the command palette (Ctrl+P on Windows), typed in "Snippets", chose "Configure User Snippets", chose Java, and it opened a JSON file where you can add custom Java snippets. From the documentation in the file, it might be more appropriate to use `$0` instead of `$2`.

Comment: @starball VS Code is obviously smart enough not to put an extra `)` when typed, why can't it be smart enough not to put an extra `;`?

Comment: loosely related things: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/8154, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64609, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68809808/11107541

Comment: silian, I've edited your title, but can you confirm whether or not it is still representative of your actual question? You seem to have rejected the workarounds people have proposed...

Comment: @starball yes, Thanks for the edit, it better represents the question I asked.

Comment: @Slaw I implemented your method today and the Tab is working fine for me and I think that's a pretty good workaround. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)